# How to backup SonarQube filters

Tags: sonarqube

There used to be a Backup button under the System menu on Sonar. It is present in 4.0, but after installing the latest version, it is simply gone. I cannot find anything in the release notes. How can I use my backup xml from 4.0 to upgrade to the latest version of sonar?

Comment: Your question in the *title* is different from your question in the *body* ... The answer you your first question is just to backup the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this feature was removed in the version 4.1.*. 
See this Jira issues [SONAR 4887](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-4887).

There is another feature to backup dashboards and filters ([SONAR 1982](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-1982)) but it is still open.